# How to use in Wordpress other menu for all pages under slash?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have WP 4, single page as hompage. I need to use other menu for all URLs under slash (e.g. /blog, /post.html, /page.html). Current code in theme's header.php:

```
            if (has_nav_menu('primary')) {
                wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary','container' => false,'menu_class' => 'nav uppercase font-primary','walker' => new Vntd_Custom_Menu_Class())); 
            } else {
                echo '<span class="vntd-no-nav">No custom menu created!</span>';
            }
```

'Primary' menu is okay for the main page, now I need to use menu ID=385 for all other URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to single out your homepage and use a different menu for all other pages. You can do this like so:

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page) {
    if (has_nav_menu('primary')) {
        wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary','container' => false,'menu_class' => 'nav uppercase font-primary','walker' => new Vntd_Custom_Menu_Class())); 
    } else {
        echo '<span class="vntd-no-nav">No custom menu created!</span>';
    }
} else {
    if (has_nav_menu('SECONDARY_MENU_NAME')) {
        wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'SECONDARY_MENU_NAME','container' => false,'menu_class' => 'nav uppercase font-secondary','walker' => new Vntd_Custom_Menu_Class())); 
    }
}
```

Replace SECONDARY_MENU_NAME with the name of the new menu you create. You will need to create this in your functions file.

Comment: Making new menu in functions.php worked fine, and I see it in backend, used it, but anyway I have only primary menu everywhere.

Comment: Yes, sure, and it worked just now, not with if(is_home() || is_front_page), but with if(is_page(pageID))